# finding the positive integre solutions $x^2+5xy=5775$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the equation: $x^2+5xy=5775$.

How can i find the positive integer solutions of it?

I can write it as $x(x+5y)=5775$ but it seems to be hard to guess.

Thanks.

Comment: well, $3,5,7,11$?

Comment: Reducing the original equation mod $5$ shows that $x \equiv 0 \bmod 5$. Does this narrow down the possibilities for you?

Comment: @david I think there are many more divisors.

Comment: @fretty - sorry but can't see how.

Comment: Ok well maybe I can write it in an elementary way. Rearranging gives $x^2 = 5775 - 5xy = 5(1155 - xy)$. Can you now see that $x$ has to be a multiple of $5$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991773/solve-this-simple-equationax2byxc-0

Answer (score 1):

$$5775=3*5*5*7*11$$
Using Fretties comment we have $x=5, 15, 35,55. $
For example $x=5,y+1=407.$

But if $x=105$ then $ 105+5y>\frac{5775}{105} $

Answer (score 0):

$x^2=5(1155-xy)$

x divided into 5 ⇨ x = 5k

$25k^2=5(1155-xy) ⇨ 5k^2 = 1155-xy ⇨ ky=231-k^2 ⇨ y={231\over k}-k$

231 divided into k.

231 dividers:

1, 3, 7, 11

21, 33, 77, 231

Check all $k<[\sqrt{231}]=15:$

for k=1 ⇨ x=5

Using $ky=231-k^2 ⇨ y=230$

...

for $k>15 ⇨ y<0$

It does not suit us. Solutions:

$x=5,y=230; x=15, y=74; x= 35, y=26; x=55, y=10.$

Comment: How does this help the OP? It doesn't explain what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

Mod 5, you can see $x\equiv0$. So $x=5k$, and now 
$$25k^2+25ky=5775$$
$$k^2+ky=231$$
$$k(k+y)=231$$
So $k$ is a factor of $231=3\cdot7\cdot11$. Since $y$ is positive, $k$ must be smaller than its cofactor $k+y$. So there are $\frac122^3=4$ options for $k$ (explicitly they are $1,3,7,11$), and then $y$ is determined as $\frac{231}{k}-k$ (and $x=5k$.)